# Bootstrap 4 - Can't get my <h2> to wrap on the XS size

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have the two columns below but the H2 in the first col-md-6 will not wrap on small screen sizes. As I resize the browser, it tends to wrap until the XS screen size and then it just becomes one long line of text.

```
<section id="hero">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 px-3">
                <h1>Selling Real Estate Just Got Easier</h1>
                <h2 style="word-wrap:break-word">Our U.S. based transaction coordinators handle contract to close so you can focus on prospecting.</h2>
                <button class="btn btn-green">Get Started</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `xs` instead of `md`?

Comment: @imvain2 - Yeah, just tried but same result. The line of text just continues off screen.

Comment: I don't understand it works without `word-wrap:break-word`  https://jsfiddle.net/y9tLu8h3/